# JQuery $post call to MVC ActionResult seems to call itself recursively - null parameter error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've just wasted half a day on this - that is a LOT of development time.  It's been a while since a bug took me quite so long to find, so I'm sharing this in case it helps anyone else.

Situation: you're good on MVC, OK on HTML but shaky on client script like JQuery.  Debugging shows that when you call a controller action something like this:

```
public ActionResult CourseNameShow(int? courseId)
        {
```

then the first time the courseId parameter is set OK, but it then seems to call itself again!  I had a JQuery call looking something like this:

```
function AfterCourseNameChoose(thisCourseId) {

   // after choosing a different course, displays its name 
    $.post("/cart/coursename/show/", { courseId: thisCourseId })
```

What could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it's all down to the HTML for the hyperlink.  I had:

```
<a href="/cart/coursename/show/" 
class="woCartButton" 
onclick="AfterCourseNameChoose($('#CourseId').val())">
```

This calls the JQuery routine shown when you click on the link, but then also goes to the URL in the HREF attribute - thus calling the controller's action twice.  The solution is to return false from the event-handler:

```
<a href="/cart/coursename/show/" 
class="woCartButton" 
onclick="return AfterCourseNameChoose($('#CourseId').val())">
```

My function then returns false:

```
function AfterCourseNameChoose(thisCourseId) {

   // after choosing a different course, displays its name 
    $.post("/cart/coursename/show/", { courseId: thisCourseId })

    .done(function (response) {
        $("#frmCourseName").html(response);
    });

    return false;

}
```

Probably really obvious to you, but overlooking the double call to the URL just cost me several hours of time!  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: A much better solution entirely would be to avoid the outdated use of the  `on*` attributes completely and use unobtrusive event handlers.